# Get rid of invisible UltraGridRow instances

Tags: ultrawingrid

I've got a grid that show tens of thousands of rows in total, obviously the user is only looking at a small fraction of those rows at any point in time, generally somewhere around 10~20 rows.

I enabled *LoadOnDemand*, which ensures that *UltraGridRow* instances and a couple of other objects will only be created when they move into the visible area:

```
grid.DisplayLayout.LoadStyle = LoadStyle.LoadOnDemand;
```

This works great (according to my memory profiler), but when I scroll up and down the whole table, i.e. trigger creation of UltraGridRows for all rows, then all UltraGridRows will get created and stay in memory forever.

How can I (ideally automatically, but if not, manually) get rid off the UltraGridRow objects for rows that are out of view? (Or just get rid of all UltraGridRows - they'll be recreated automatically anyway)

One brute force way I figured out is this:

```
var tmp = grid.DataSource;
grid.DataSource = null;
grid.DataSource = tmp;
```

It causes some side effects though, so is there some other way to get rid of UltraGridRows?

Btw, I tried these two guys, without success (trying *true* and *false* for the bool params).

```
grid.Rows.Refresh(RefreshRow.ReloadData, false, true);
grid.Rows.DeallocateCells(true);
```

I'm trying to get memory consumption down, and UltraGridRows are currently the main consumer (UltraGridRows by themselves aren't huuuge, they consume under 200 bytes each, which in my case means a couple of megabytes, just so you know what we are talking about).

This is Infragistics 9.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's always reflection...

```
var m = typeof(RowsCollection)
    .GetMethod("InternalClearHelper", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
m.Invoke(grid.Rows, null);
```

This actually works for me, but it will clear the selection, so you have to remember that before invoking and restore the selection afterwards.